# Suppress BTExplorer when another application needs to access the bluetooth connection (Bluetopia)

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am developing a C# device application for Motorola MC55 devices (**Bluetopia** is used). This application sets the bluetooth inquiry and pairing procedure in motion (by means of the **Enterprise Mobility Developer Kit**) and writes down the **virtual serial port** #:

```
public void DoConnection(IRemoteBTDevice rd)
{
    RemoteDevice remoteDevice = new RemoteDevice(rd.DeviceName, rd.Id.Replace(":", ""), "");

    this.bluetooth.RemoteDevices.Add(remoteDevice);
    this.bluetooth.RemoteDevices.Refresh();

    if (!remoteDevice.IsPaired)
    {
        remoteDevice.Pair(rd.Pin);
    }

    //TODO Note serial port # (get it by means of remoteDevice.LocalComPort) 

    //Works smoothly, but a second process has to do this (requirement).
    remoteDevice.OpenPort();
}
```

But as soon as a second process (e.g. another c# device application) opens that serial port, BTExplorer is launched. How do I suppress this phenomenon?

```
this.comX = new SerialPort(this.BluetoothPortName);
this.comX.Open();
```

I'm just using another Assembly: http://32feet.codeplex.com/. It works smoothly for Motorola ES400 (Microsoft Stack). After seeing this: http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Stonestreet%20One%20Bluetopia, I used the same code, but it doesn't work trouble-free for MC55 yet.

Thank you for your support,
Roger Huber

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, it is BTExplorer.exe that actually provides/controls the virtual COM port service, so it needs to be running when a virtual COM port is in use...

Do be sure to let know what the issues you see on your MC55 when using my 32feet.NET Bluetopia support.  As I noted at [32feet.NET: Stonestreet One Bluetopia](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Stonestreet%20One%20Bluetopia) I tested on a M3 Mobile device which has a quite recent version of the Bluetopia stack.  Maybe StoneStreetOne changed something between your versions...  (If Bluetopia start-up fails completely then I've more logging in [version 3.3](http://32feet.codeplex.com/releases/view/72845) -- which I'm not too far away from releasing).

Of course if that second C# program needs to use a virtual COM port then 32feet.NET won't help -- BTExplorer is still required as discussed above.  However if you could change that program to use BluetoothClient etc instead of COM ports...  (Remembering of course the "Bluetopia one at a time" restriction of course).

Alan

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Using Blutopia stack:

- 32Feet.NET: DeviceName property of BluetoothDeviceInfo class gets Bluetooth address of the corresponding device (instead of friendly name).
- EMDK: SuD behaves in an odd way. BTExplorer will no longer be launched.

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft stack temporarily (Motorola dual Bluetooth stack support). But I'm keeping close to list cause and effect with regard to above-mentioned.

Comment: Name lookup take time in Bluetooth (prior to version 2.1) as I note at http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DeviceName%20and%20Discovery  It has to be done separately from discovery, so do as recommended there and after a wee while call device.Refresh() and the access DeviceName again and hopefully the name will have been found.

Comment: Bluetopia is a bit worse than the other stacks as it doesn't help with the name-lookup process but it has to be done manually.  The client that supported the Bluetopia work was happy with the current state but I had some ideas to look at to and improve it... :-)